# Incrementing charaters past 'Z' in Java like a Spreadsheet

Tags: java, char, spreadsheet

I didn't start too long ago with programming, and currently I need a method to produce an array, containing a character which is comes after the previous character. It should start with an 'A' at 0, then a B at '1' etc.. The hard part is making it so that after the 'Z' comes 'AA'.

What I came up with:

```
public static String[] charArray(int length)
{   
    String[] res = new String[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        String name = "";
        int colNumber = i;
        while(colNumber > 0)
        {
            char c = (char) ('A' + (colNumber % 26));
            name = c + name;
            colNumber = colNumber / 26;
        }
        res[i] = name;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This works fine for the first 26 letters of the alphabet, but it produces "... Y, Z, BA, BB, BC..." instead of "... Y, Z, AA, AB, AC..."

What's wrong? Or are there any more efficient or easier ways to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To figure out why you get the output you're getting all you need to do is think about your variables for a few minutes. And maybe print some additional info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had a nice start. Instead of running through the while loop this example basically calculates the value of C based on the number % 26

Then the letter is added (concatenated) to the value within the array at the position: `(index / 26) - 1` which ensures it's keeping up with the changes over time.

When iterating through on the first go, you'll have only one letter in each slot in the array `A B C` etc.

Once you've run through the alphabet, you'll then have an index that looks backwards and adds the current letter to that value.

You'll eventually get into AAA AAB AAC etc. or even more.

```
    public static String[] colArray(int length) {   

    String[] result = new String[length];

    String colName = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        char c = (char)('A' + (i % 26));
        colName = c + "";
        if(i > 25){
            colName =  result[(i / 26) - 1] + "" + c;
        }
        result[i] = colName;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This works exactly like intended. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Emiel no problem. If this worked for you, be sure to accept the answer. Accepting answers is just as important as asking questions around here. =]

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
public static String[] charArray(int length)
{   
    String[] res = new String[length];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; counter < length; i++)
    {
        String name = "";
        int colNumber = i;
        while(colNumber > 0 && colNumber % 27 != 0)
        {  
            char c = (char) ('A' + ((colNumber) % 27) - 1);
            name = c + name;
            colNumber = colNumber / 27;
        }
        res[counter] = name;

        if (i % 27 != 0) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Basically your algorithm skipped all elements starting with an A (A, AA, AB, ...) (because an A is created when colNumber is 0, but this never happens because your while terminates in that case). Taking modulo of 27 and then actually subtracting 1 after from the char fixes this issue. Then we use `counter` as index as otherwise we would end up with some empty elements in the array (the ones where `i` would be `i % 27 == 0`).

Comment: @RichardTingle you are right. We have to execute the `for` loop not until `i` equals `length`, but until our index `counter` equals the length. I made an edit which should work fine now.

Comment: This also doesn't work after the value ZZ. It prints the alphabet and then does some weird stuff before going into the tripple digits.

Comment: This works exactly like intended. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me. Having 26 vocabulary letters and knowing that  65 is the char 'A' in ASCII table, we can get the incrementing with this recursive method...

```
private fun indexLetters(index: Int, prefix: String = "") : String {
    val indexSuffix:Int = index.rem(26)
    val suffix = (65 + indexSuffix).toChar().toString().plus(".")
    val newPrefix = suffix.plus(prefix)

    val indexPrefix: Int = index / 26
    return if (indexPrefix > 0) {
        indexLetters(indexPrefix - 1, newPrefix)
    } else {
        newPrefix
    }
}
```

You can call this kotlin method like

```
indexLetters(0) //To get an 'A'
indexLetters(25) //To get a 'Z'
indexLetters(26) //To get an 'A.A'
etcetera...
```

from an array iteration, depending of your requirements